# How to connect desktop PC and MBP to duel monitors

Tags: displayport, kvm-switch

I think i might be making this harder than it needs to be...

I have a desktop, a Macbook Pro, and 2 monitors. I'd like to connect the PC and MBP to a toggle of sorts so that i can shift between my MBP or Desktop being displayed on both monitors, KVM seems to be my best bet according to microcenter. Mouse/Keyboard are unique to each setup so i don't need peripherals (ethernet can go to PC, my MBP can be wireless). So what am i missing here. IOGEAR sells a few high end devices but without needing to share peripherals/ehternet is a KVM switch overkill? Or at least a $300 one.

Would greatly appreciate any advice and apologies if i've misunderstood anything in advance.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You may share your screen via HDMI on the MBP (thru a Thunderbolt-to-HDMI), and Displayport on the PC.
Two cables on the screen.

If not possible, revert them: HDMI on the laptop, DisplayPort on the MBP directly thru the Thunderbolt port.

Comment: So is this the "daisy chain" method i've read about? Monitor links to monitor which then connects to a switch?

Comment: No, daisy chain is connecting more than one monitor to a single computer.

Answer (score 0):

Most monitors support more than one input. Just choose the appropriate connectors or adapters to connect the two systems to the screen.

Adapters and cables are much cheaper than KVM and if all you need to switch is the screen, that's all you need.